# How to use cbind to add a vector to a dataframe that has different number of rows

Tags: multiple-columns, cbind

I'm trying to add a column within my dataframe with the values stored in a vector, but I'm getting the error message `Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :  arguments imply differing number of rows: 82, 63`

This is the code I used:

`Patient5GeneExpressionProfile <- cbind(Patient5GeneExpressionProfile, geneclusters)`